# Django : NoReverseMatch error when reverse a url

Tags: django

while redirecting to particular url i am trying to pass a variable (`cat`) to a view. using the `reverse` 
like :

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('show_poll'), args=[cat])
```

above redirect will go to a following view :

```
def show_poll(request, cat):
    print cat
```

having url as

```
 url(r'^show/(?P<cat>\w+)/$',  'pollsite.views.show_poll', name="show_poll"),
```

getting : `Reverse for 'show_poll' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `args` to `reverse()` as

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('show_poll', args=[cat]))
#-----------------------------------------------^ closing bracket moved at the end
```